# SQL MIN DATE >= 2017-01

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I got table with columns [TagTime], [TagValue], [id]. Values in this table comming every 15 min, so there is multiple values with the same id's.

I want select (tagtime,tagvalue,id), that will  return only first value in january 2017 for all the id's.

I tried with select top 1, then with group by, distinct... but it doesnt work. Have you some suggestions?

Comment: add sample data with expected o/p

Comment: Share us your written code that did not succeded, also tag a dbms you are using

Comment: Share some written code, data type of the columns.

Comment: What does `only first value` mean? Is it a value with the smallest `id`?

Comment: only first value mean first value in 2017

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I assumed you are using MSSQL)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [tbl1]
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,TagTime) = '01' AND DATEPART(YEAR,TagTime) = '2017'
ORDER BY TagTime DESC
```

Comment: this will return only 1 row, not 1 row for every Id as OP is expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way

```
select id, tagvalue, tagtime 
from
     (select id, tagvalue, tagtime, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by tagtime) [RowNum]
      from YourTable
      where DATEPART(year, tagtime) = 2017) src
where src.[RowNum] = 1
```

So, you having row number for each ID, ordered by tagtime, and then selecting just first of every ID

Comment: but where is jan 2017?

Comment: it Works well. What about if i want this view not for exactly January 2017, but for the current month?

Comment: In that case change 'order by tagtime desc' ... that will give you last insert of the 2017 year (newest inserts), but if you want to get 1st day of current month, you have to change where DATEPART(year, tagtime) = 2017 AND DATEPART(month, tagtime) = 1 (or number of month you wish for)

Comment: it Works well. Thank you my friend!